# Explaining the integral of Laplacian of $r \mapsto \frac1r$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, polar-coordinates, laplacian

Consider the function $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$f(x,y,z) = \frac1{\left( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right)^{\frac12}}$$

or, written in polar coordinates, $f (r) = \frac1r$.

The Laplacian $\nabla^2 f \equiv \nabla \cdot (\nabla f)$ can be computed as $0$ everywhere except the origin. Is there a way to rigorously define its value at the origin, and a concept of integration, such that

$$\int_{\Bbb R^3} \nabla^2 f = -4\pi?$$

(This is a result I saw in a physics textbook that was computed by non-rigorous means.)

If not, what does the previous integral expression actual mean, mathematically?

Comment: The Laplacian of $1/r$ is: "An object that, when integrated over *any* volume excluding the origin, yields zero, and when integrated over *any* volume including the origin, yields $-4\pi$". This statement follows from direct computation. It is a lot of words. Fortunately, we have a symbol due to Dirac that abbreviates these words: $\delta(r)$. It is clear that, whatever you want to call it, this object is not a regular function, as the 'value' at a single point (here, the origin) contributes to the integral.

Comment: What kind of "function" is it? And what kind of "integral" is defined for it?

Comment: It is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\nabla\frac1{|r|}=-\frac{r}{|r|^3}$. From there, we can compute that away from $0$, $\Delta\frac1{|r|}=0$. However, if we use the Divergence Theorem,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|r|\lt\alpha}\Delta\frac1{|r|}\,\mathrm{d}V
&=\int_{|r|\lt\alpha}\nabla\cdot\left(-\frac{r}{|r|^3}\right)\mathrm{d}V\tag1\\
&=\int_{|r|=\alpha}n\cdot\left(-\frac{r}{|r|^3}\right)\mathrm{d}S\tag2\\
&=\int_{|r|=\alpha}\frac{r}{|r|}\cdot\left(-\frac{r}{|r|^3}\right)\mathrm{d}S\tag3\\
&=-\int_{|r|=\alpha}\frac1{|r|^2}\,\mathrm{d}S\tag4\\[6pt]
&=-4\pi\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\nabla\frac1{|r|}=-\frac{r}{|r|^3}$
$(2)$: [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Mathematical_statement)
$(3)$: $n=\frac{r}{|r|}$
$(4)$: simplify the dot product
$(5)$: the surface area of the sphere $|r|=\alpha$ is $4\pi\alpha^2$

Since $\Delta\frac1{|r|}=0$ away from $0$, we get
$$
\int_\Omega\Delta\frac1{|r|}\,\mathrm{d}V=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
0&\text{if }0\not\in\overline\Omega\\
-4\pi&\text{if }0\in\overline\Omega
\end{array}\right.\tag6
$$
That is, $\Delta\frac1{|r|}$ is $-4\pi\delta$ where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).